# Substring метод

Tags: java

```
class StringReplace{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String org="This is a test. This is,too".";
        String search="is";
        String sub="was";
        String result="";
        int=i;
        do{
            System.out.println(org);
            i=org.indexOf(search);
            if(i !=-1){
                result=org.substring(0,i);
                result=result+sub;
                result=result+org.substring(i+search.length());
                org=result;
            }
        }while(i!=-1);
    }
}
```

ВОПРОС: что происходит здесь? `result=org.substring(0,i)`;

Comment: создается строка, содержащая символы строки в `org` от 0 включая, до `i` не включая (т.е. от начала строки до начала заменяемой подстроки) ([сотв. javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)), присваивается `result`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Если вопрос в механизме создания новой строки то тело метода substring выглядит так:

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];

public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

как мы видим используется один из конструкторов класса java.lang.String

```
public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    }
    if (count <= 0) {
        if (count < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(count);
        }
        if (offset <= value.length) {
            this.value = "".value;
            return;
        }
    }
    // Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
    if (offset > value.length - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + count);
    }
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
}
```

т.е создается массив символов и хранится в новом экземпляре класса.

Answer (score 1):

```
substring
```

Вы можете извлечь подстроку из объекта `String`, используя метод `sub­string`. Этот метод создает новую копию символов из того диапазона ин­дексов оригинальной строки, который вы указали при вызове. Можно указать только индекс первого символа нужной подстроки — тогда будут скопированы все символы, начиная с указанного и до конца строки. Также можно указать и начальный, и конечный индексы — при этом в новую строку будут скопированы все символы, начиная с первого ука­занного, и до (но не включая его) символа, заданного конечным индек­сом.

```
"Hello World".substring(6) -> "World" 

"Hello World".substring(3,8) -> "lo Wo"
```

Answer (score 0):

В строку `result` запишется строковое значение переменной `org`, но не все, а определенные символы - с первого до i, если я не ошибаюсь не включая. То есть если, например, `i = 5`, то строковая переменная `result` будет равна "This".